# Monitoring message delivery on Postfix (or Cyrus IMAP)

Tags: email, postfix, monitoring

There's mail server based on Postfix. I need to monitor which messages are delivered to end-user? and which are not. In processing of each message I need to get some information from its attachment in XML format. How can I monitor delivery messages this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I need to monitor which messages are delivered to end-user? and which
>   are not

All failed and successful deliveries are logged to `/var/log/maillog`. You may want to use the Nagios's [check_logfiles](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files/check_logfiles/details) plugin:

```
Name       : check_logfiles
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 3.4.2
Release    : 1.el5.rf
Size       : 39 k
Repo       : rpmforge
Summary    : Logfile check  plugin for nagios
URL        : http://sourceforge.net/projects/check-logfiles
License    : GPL
Description: check_logfiles is a plugin for Nagios which searches for patterns in logfiles. It is capable of scanning
           : multiple logfiles and their rotated ancestors in a single run.
```

Define a command to check this file:

```
command[check_postfix]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logfiles \
    --tag=postfix \
    --logfile=/var/log/maillog \
    --warningpattern="warning" \
    --criticalpattern="critical"
```

A sample result:

> OK - no errors or warnings|postfix_lines=0 postfix_warnings=0
>   postfix_criticals=0 postfix_unknowns=0

---

> In processing of each message I need to get some information from its
>   attachment in XML format

Do you mean you want to filter some attachment file types. And if so, take a look at the [mime_header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mime_header_checks) directive.

Define a header checks by adding the following line to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
```

Append some file extensions to this file:

```
/name=[^>]*\.(exe|bat|bin|sh)/ REJECT
```

Restart Postfix and test with `mutt`:

```
echo "hello" | mutt -s "Test mail" -a attach.sh your.email@domain.com
```

you should see the rejected message in the log file:

> Nov  9 11:35:08 199 postfix/cleanup[27318]: F1649BFB0176: reject: header Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="attach.sh" from local; from= to=: 5.7.1 message
>   content rejected