# Monitoring message delivery on Postfix (or Cyrus IMAP)

Tags: email, monitoring, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring message delivery on Postfix (or Cyrus IMAP)](https://serverfault.com/questions/329142/monitoring-message-delivery-on-postfix-or-cyrus-imap)

There's mail server based on Postfix. I need to monitor which messages are delivered to end-user? and which are not. In processing of each message I need to get some information from its  attachment in XML format.
How can I monitor delivery messages this way?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an API to get the delivery status from postfix, you'd probably have to do log parsing. Attachment info extract could probably be done through a [fm]ilter. I suggest you ask this question on serverfault, since it is not an actual programming question.

Answer (score 0):

you can verify this by by running this script:

> tail -f /var/log/maillog | grep -i status

Through this command, you will see a list of all emails, which are Being sent , rejected or else.

you can see count of sent mails through this command

> grep -i status /var/log/maillog | grep -i sent | wc -l