# Rejecting bad attachments best practice?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, sendmail

When configuring a mail server, what is the best practice for rejecting an inbound internet email with an executable type I'd like to disallow? Easiest option is an NDR/DSN, but I'd think that could put one at risk to create backscatter.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/329162

Answer (score 3):

When the mail server is sendmail, I install [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) use it to enforce attachment policy.

Comment: ...which is especially useful since it is a so-called "milter" and allows for real-time filtering. This way, the mail server simply would send a reject response upon reception of the DATA section - NDRs would be someone else's problem then. Sendmail is not the only mailserver to support this, [Postfix' before-queue content filters](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html) will do the same.

Comment: Thanks guys. I read that many MTAs won't honor a reject code like 550 during the DATA section of the conversation, which is concerning.